# IOS- use setting bundle in app ？

Tags: ios

My app need an inside setting view, and I want to create a custom view with setting bundle.It suggests two way:

1. use a table view and UISwitch,UISlider...
2. use some open source framework like [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit).

Which is better? Or is there a better way for this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use CoreData to saving setting value,than you can use custom componts

Answer (score 0):

Settings page of the app have a lot of limitations, you cannot use custom layouts, controls, only that which are available in the `Settings.bundle`. So you can use only them and construct that page in "manual mode" or use that library which you have mentioned in your question. The result will be same, it is totally opinion based and which is easier for you would be the right way